# Font change during boot sequence

Tags: kernel, fonts, console

When you boot the Linux kernel, it spews fouth a huge wall of text, which scrolls faster than any human could ever read. If you watch closely, at some point during the boot sequence, the font the text is drawn with changes ever so slightly.

Does anybody know why this happens, or exactly what point it happens at? It's not a problem, I'm just curious to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font change happens because `setfont` is run to change the font. On Debian-based distributions, this is usually done by [`console-setup`](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/console-setup).

By default, the effect is as you describe: in Debian, on PCs with kernel mode-setting, the default switches from whatever 8×16 font is included in the kernel to Terminus 8×16, the default font in `console-setup`.